# Outlook VSTO - DAST query returning condition is not valid

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to search for appointment on a shared calendar. The first step is I am saving the appointment in shared calendar with a custom property **twMeetingId**. This is working fine:

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem nurseAppointment = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetSharedDefaultFolder(recepient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.Add();
nurseAppointment.UserProperties.Add("twMeetingId", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
nurseAppointment.UserProperties["twMeetingId"].Value = appointmentData.meetingId;
nurseAppointment.Save();
```

Then I am trying to find any appointments in the same shared calendar based on the custom property **twMeetingId**

```
var filter = $"@SQL =\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/twMeetingId/0000001f\" = '{appointmentData.meetingId}'";
Outlook.Items items = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetSharedDefaultFolder(recepient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.Restrict(filter);
```

At this point I am receiving an error "Condition not valid". I have checked the meetingId value is correct in the filter. I have also tried to use Jet query as below but it also does not work:

```
nurseAppointment = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetSharedDefaultFolder(recepient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.Find(String.Format("[twMeetingId] = '{0}'", appointmentData.meetingId));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an erroneous space between `@SQL` and `=`. The following condition worked without error for me:

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/twMeetingId/0000001f" = 'test'
```

Also make sure `appointmentData.meetingId` does not contain any characters that need to be encoded.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies it is really embarrassing silly mistake that I should have reviewed before posting

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have got a wrongly composed search string in the code:

```
var filter = $"@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/twMeetingId\" = '{appointmentData.meetingId}'";
```

First, as you can see you need to use a single curly braces in the search string.

Second, you need to remove the property type in the end of DASL property name.

If you want to use the property name without DASL namespaces like that:

```
"[twMeetingId] = '{0}'"
```

You need to make sure the property is added to the folder fields when you call `UserProperties.Add` method. The `AddToFolderFields` parameter is `true` if the property will be added as a custom field to the folder that the item is in. This field can be displayed in the folder's view. `alse` if the property will be added as a custom field to the item but not to the folder. The default value is True.

You may find the [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filtering-items-using-query-keywords) article helpful.

Comment: string interpolation (`$"..."`) requires double `{{` and `}}` to encode single `{` and `}`. The property type (`0000001f`) is also fully supported in DASL queries. It is the only way to query properties of type other than string (which is assumed by default if the type is not specified).

Comment: Then what do you think could cause a problem?

Comment: In my case, each search only required 2 hour timeframe between start date and end date. I ended up looping through all appointments after restricting them by datetime. It is probably not the most efficient solution but I could not find any other way